# How to append new Array in JSON file stored in android

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have one JSON file in my app's data folder.

```
 {
  "user": [
    {
      "identifier": "1",
      "name": "xyz",
      "contact": [
        {
          "contact": "123"
        },
        {
          "contact": "456"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to add a new user at runtime like this.

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "identifier": "1",
      "name": "xyz",
      "contact": [
        {
          "contact": "123"
        },
        {
          "contact": "456"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "user": [
    {
      "identifier": "2",
      "name": "abc",
      "contact": [
        {
          "contact": "445"
        },
        {
          "contact": "789"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For that, I have this code but it simply overrides the existing user.

```
String lastObject = getStringFronFile(new FileInputStream(file));
        try {
            JSONObject prevJSONObj = new JSONObject(lastObject);
            prevJSONObj.put("sticker_packs",newUserArray);
            writeJsonFile(file,prevJSONObj);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Json Error", e.toString());
        }
```

`writeJsonFile` is a method for writing in the file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The structure you defined above is wrong, you cannot define two node with the same name `user` in a JSONObject.

If you want to store a list of user in to a file, you may store it like:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Jack",
        "age" :20
    },
    {
        "name":"Tom",
        "age" :20
    }
]
```

By the way, why not use SQLite database?

Comment: Thanks for giving you valuable answer. I am new to android so I ma learning and I am surely use SQLite database in future.

Answer (score 0):

Gson simplifies this work. Add the gson dependency https://github.com/google/gson or retrofit's gson (both are same) 
`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'`. From your details constructed the following pojo classes :

```
public class Example {
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private List<User> user = null;

public List<User> getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(List<User> user) {
this.user = user;
}
}

public class User {
@SerializedName("identifier")
@Expose
private String identifier;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("contact")
@Expose
private List<Contact> contact = null;

public String getIdentifier() {
return identifier;
}

public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
this.identifier = identifier;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<Contact> getContact() {
return contact;
}

public void setContact(List<Contact> contact) {
this.contact = contact;
}
}

public class Contact {
@SerializedName("contact")
@Expose
private String contact;

public String getContact() {
return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
this.contact = contact;
}
}
```

You can use the following snippet to get details from string and append your dynamic data and update the file.

```
String lastObject = getStringFromFile(new FileInputStream(file));
Example newJsonToReplace = new Example();
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList();
try{
    Type typeOfObject = new TypeToken<Example>() {
    }.getType(); // type you will be getting from string
    Example example = new Gson().fromJson(lastObject, typeOfObject); // converting string to pojo using gson
    if(example != null){
        usersList.addAll(example.getUser());
    }
    usersList.add(yourYourToAdd); // add your user object
    newJsonToReplace.setUser(usersList);
    String updatedList = new Gson().toJson(newJsonToReplace, typeOfObject); // again converting to json to string
    writeJsonFile(updatedList); // will replace the existing content
}catch(Exception exception){
    Log.d("Json Error", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer it helps me a lot.